# How to create array in postgres based on unique values from the same table joined twice?

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, jsonb, array-agg

I have a query which in I joined twice the same table, i.e:

```
left join tag tag1 [...]
left join tag tag2 [...]
```

I would like to have query with one column called `tag` which in I will have unique values from both tables (`tag1`, `tag2`).

*Example:*
For now I am able to select unique values from each one column with `jsonb_agg(distinct tag_name)` and in my query I have two columns:

```
tag1            | tag2
[Sport, Music]  | [Sport, Games]
```

And I would like to have one column with unique values from `tag1` and `tag2` like:

```
tag
[Sport, Music, Games]
```

Answer (score 0):

If tag1 and tag2 are two tables with the same column tag_name, then you can use `UNION`  in order to merge the values from both tables while avoiding duplicates :

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(r.tag_name)
FROM
(
SELECT tag_name
  FROM tag1
UNION
SELECT tag_name
  FROM tag2
) AS r
```